# How figure out how many sd cards android device carries

Tags: android, filesystems

I found that using Environment object isn't reliable;e to determinate SD card. Actually it works, however sometimes tells like as no SD card, so I use just direct mount as /sdcard and it works. Now I realized that a device may have several SD cards. My device report it as external-sdcard, so I can access this card as /external-sdcard or /sdcard/external-sdcard. Now question, how to figure out type of a particular mount? I can traverse directory, but File object doesn't have any attribute telling me I am SD card. I remember regular Java provides FileSystem objects which I can use to inspect particular files and this object can tell me if a File object is simple file, or it is drive, or it is external drive. Is something like that available for Android?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the currently documented API only supports one SD card (actually external storage). 
You can use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the directory, and `Enviroment.getExternalStorageState()` to check if it is mounted.

Anything besides that seems to be (currently) unsupported. 
Bearing that in mind, you could parse `/proc/mounts` to find out what file systems are mounted where.